# How to fix Flutter build_runner error: Failed to precompile build_runner:build_runner:

Tags: flutter, build-runner

I'm working on two Flutter projects, one of them has already been migrated to null safety and uses **Flutter 2.0.5**. The second project, the one that causes the issues, is not yet migrated to null safety and uses **Flutter 1.22.6**. Switching projects is done by just renaming the Flutter SDK folder.

Now the problem is that `build_runner` only works for **Flutter 2.0.5**. When calling `flutter pub run build_runner build` from inside the **Flutter 1.22.6** project, it fails
with the following error messages:

```
Failed to precompile build_runner:build_runner:
../../../Flutter%20SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http_multi_server-2.1.0/lib/src/multi_headers.dart:97:8: Error: The method 'MultiHeaders.add' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'HttpHeaders.add'.
  void add(String name, Object value) {
       ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///sdk/lib/_http/http.dart:698:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('add').
  void add(String name, Object value,
       ^
../../../Flutter%20SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http_multi_server-2.1.0/lib/src/multi_headers.dart:129:8: Error: The method 'MultiHeaders.set' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'HttpHeaders.set'.
  void set(String name, Object value) {
       ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///sdk/lib/_http/http.dart:707:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('set').
  void set(String name, Object value,
       ^
../../../Flutter%20SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/build_runner-1.11.0/lib/src/entrypoint/runner.dart:23:31: Error: No named parameter with the name 'usageLineLength'.
  final argParser = ArgParser(usageLineLength: lineLength);
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter%20SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/args-1.4.4/lib/src/arg_parser.dart:43:11: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  factory ArgParser({bool allowTrailingOptions: true}) =>
          ^
../../../Flutter%20SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/build_runner-1.11.0/bin/src/commands/clean.dart:18:31: Error: No named parameter with the name 'usageLineLength'.
  final argParser = ArgParser(usageLineLength: lineLength);
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter%20SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/args-1.4.4/lib/src/arg_parser.dart:43:11: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  factory ArgParser({bool allowTrailingOptions: true}) =>
          ^
../../../Flutter%20SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/build_runner-1.11.0/bin/src/commands/generate_build_script.dart:18:31: Error: No named parameter with the name 'usageLineLength'.
  final argParser = ArgParser(usageLineLength: lineLength);
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Flutter%20SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/args-1.4.4/lib/src/arg_parser.dart:43:11: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  factory ArgParser({bool allowTrailingOptions: true}) =>
```

Oddly enough all of these errors are outside the project.
Calling `flutter clean` and `flutter pub cache repair` has no effect. So the question is, what needs to be done to get `build_runner` working on (the now obsolete) `Flutter version 1.22.6`?
Your advise is very much welcome, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a required third party library prevented migrating to null safety, the only solution was to eliminate build_runner by switching from generated json to hand written one.

More a workaround than a solution, but it sufficed.